# Ubuntu 16.04 snap connection refused

Tags: connection, snap

I have a problem with my Ubuntu. I try to install with 'snap' a package but every time I try to install this package it comes a Error with "connection Refused".

Have Somebody a Idea how I can Fix it ?

Best regards Dano!

[Console Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywjat.png)

Im not using iPv6. My Ubuntu use iPv4 for the connection to the network.

Comment: Looks like you're using ipv6 to connect. The store is only available over ipv4, so you probably need to disable ipv6.

Comment: Im not using ipv6. Im using ipv4. I think thats not the problem

Comment: Also having this problem :/